# Bootstrap 4 Text Input ID

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Is there a way within the Bootstrap UI to add an ID to a text input field?
I can't see an option under text input > options.

ie I want to add
`id="bo1_r_suburb"`
to`<div class="col"><label class="col-form-label">Suburb</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="bo1_r_suburb"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want..

```
<div class="col"><label class="col-form-label">Suburb</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="bo1_r_suburb" id="bo1_r_suburb"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it is... but how do I can I add the id attribute within the bootstrap user interface? I'd rather not have to change the HTML file directly and not use custom code in bootstrap

Comment: @Ashman ..I dont understand exactly where you want to change. A screenshot may help to get you issue more clearly.

Comment: https://ibb.co/xgZDSkt      Can I add the ID within this menu? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry.
I meant bootstrap studio.
I've figured out I do have to use custom code within bootstrap studio